# Python input() function to store user input in either list or tuple or dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, input

```
words = input("Enter a word to find its length: ")

for x in words:
    print x, len(x)
```

I want to this code to work for user input at runtime so that user input can be stored in word and can be used in runtime in for loop.

How should it be done?

Comment: Doesn't it works as is?

Comment: I believe he's wants the user to be able to enter multiple words

Comment: list = [None]*3
x = True
z = 0
while z < 3:
 y = raw_input("Enter a word to find its length: ")
 if(y == "n"):
  x = False;
 else:
  list[z] = y;
  print len(list[z]);
  z +=1   //This is answer that I ve found myself an this time its working

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [None]*3
x = True

z = 0
while z < 3:
    y = raw_input("Enter a word to find its length: ")
    if(y == "n"):
        x = False;
    else:
        list[z] = y;
        print len(list[z]);
        z +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more Pythonic:

```
result = [None] * 3
for index in range(len(result)):
    y = raw_input("Enter a word to find its length: ")
    if y == "n":
        break
    else:
        result[index] = y
        print len(result[index])
```